# How do I unwrap an Optional when pattern matching tuples in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pattern-matching, option-type

In Swift, there's a common `if let` pattern used to unwrap optionals:

```
if let value = optional {
    print("value is now unwrapped: \(value)")
}
```

I'm currently doing this kind of pattern matching, but with tuples in a switch case, where both params are optionals:

```
//url is optional here
switch (year, url) {
    case (1990...2015, let unwrappedUrl):
        print("Current year is \(year), go to: \(unwrappedUrl)")
}
```

However, this prints:

```
"Current year is 2000, go to Optional(www.google.com)"
```

Is there a way I can unwrap my optional and pattern match only if it's not nil? Currently my workaround is this:

```
switch (year, url) {
    case (1990...2015, let unwrappedUrl) where unwrappedUrl != nil:
        print("Current year is \(year), go to: \(unwrappedUrl!)")
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `x?` pattern:

```
case (1990...2015, let unwrappedUrl?):
    print("Current year is \(year), go to: \(unwrappedUrl)")
```

`x?` is just a shortcut for `.some(x)`, so this is equivalent to

```
case (1990...2015, let .some(unwrappedUrl)):
    print("Current year is \(year), go to: \(unwrappedUrl)")
```

Answer (score 1):

with a switch case you can unwrap (when needed) and also evaluate the unwrapped values (by using where) in the same case.

Like this:

```
let a: Bool? = nil
let b: Bool? = true

switch (a, b) {
case let (unwrappedA?, unwrappedB?) where unwrappedA || unwrappedB:
  print ("A and B are not nil, either A or B is true")
case let (unwrappedA?, nil) where unwrappedA:
  print ("A is True, B is nil")
case let (nil, unwrappedB?) where unwrappedB:
  print ("A is nil, B is True")
default:
  print("default case")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
switch(year, x) {
    case (1990...2015, .Some):
    print("Current year is \(year), go to: \(x!)")
}
```

and you can also do

```
 switch(year, x) {
    case (1990...2015, let .Some(unwrappedUrl)):
    print("Current year is \(year), go to: \(unwrappedUrl)")
}
```

Comment: In this example, it works, but I didn't actually want to use an explicit unwrap operator, because I will be using that variable more than once. Is there a way to just unwrap it into another variable?

Comment: then you can do like
 case (1990...2015, let .Some(unwrappedUrl)):
as @Martin R did.