# How to use Optional Ints in a Switch statement

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, switch-statement, option-type

I have made some progress on my app to play RoShambo, but am stumped on one particular thing. In one ViewController, I have established two properties of the class. I want them to be integers because I use a switch statement later on in the class with integers. However, I get an error when I use integers saying:

```
"Class 'ResultsViewController' has no initializers"
"stored property 'your play' without initial value prevents synthesized initializers"
```

Now, those errors go away if I make my stored properties optionals, but then I get errors on my switch statement because it uses integers, not optionals.

So I have two questions: 1) In the switch statement I have below, how would I use values of type "Int?" in a switch statement?

2) If my optional values are nil, how could I end the program and not conduct the switch statement, since it wouldn't make sense to conduct the comparison?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Properties

var opponentPlay: Int?
var yourPlay: Int?

//Mark: Outlets

@IBOutlet weak var MatchResult: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var PlayAgainButton: UIButton!


//Mark: Life Cycle

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        //unwrap optional properties
        if let opponentPlay = opponentPlay {
            print("good play")
        } else {
            print("opponentPlay is nil")

        }

        if let yourPlay = yourPlay {
            print("good play")
        } else {
            print("opponentPlay is nil")
        }


    switch (opponentPlay, yourPlay) {
        case (1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2), (3, 3), (3, 3):
            self.MatchResult.text = "You Tie!"
        case (1, 2):
            self.MatchResult.text = "You Win!"
        case (2, 1):
            self.MatchResult.text = "You Lose!"
        case (1, 3):
            self.MatchResult.text = "You Lose!"
        case (3, 1):
            self.MatchResult.text = "You Win!"
        case (2, 3):
            self.MatchResult.text = "You Win!"
        case (3, 2):
            self.MatchResult.text = "You Lose!"
        default:
            break
    }
```

Comment: Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37452118/6541007).

Answer (score 1):

You can unwrap with `?`. You can also add `where` clauses if you don't want to enumerate each permutation whether you win and where you lose:

```
switch (opponentPlay, yourPlay) {
case (nil, nil):
    print("both nil")
case (nil, _):
    print("opponent score nil")
case (_, nil):
    print("yours is nil")
case (let opponent?, let yours?) where opponent == yours:
    matchResult.text = "tie"
case (let opponent?, let yours?) where opponent > yours:
    matchResult.text = "you win"
case (let opponent?, let yours?) where opponent < yours:
    matchResult.text = "you lose"
default:
    fatalError("you should never get here")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have executed this code similar to yours and it does not generate errors. I really do not know if switch accepts optionals, but I think in this case it is not necessary either. I hope it will be useful to you.

```
var opponentPlay: Int?
var yourPlay: Int?
var matchResult = ""

func play (){
  if let opponentPlay = opponentPlay , let yourplay = yourPlay {
    switch (opponentPlay,yourplay) {
    case (1,1):
        matchResult = "You tie"
    default:
        break
    }
  }
}
```